# Distribution of the Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, expected-value, covariance

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be the standard wiener process and define:

$$X_{t} = \frac{B_{t+h} - B_t}{h} \quad , \quad h > 0.$$

Now I'm asked to prove that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Gaussian Process and calculate its mean $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ and covariance $Cov(X_t, X_0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Well, the sum of any two Normals is a Normal. Note that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[B_{t+h}] - \mathbb{E}[B_t]}{h}
$$
and can you now compute $\mathbb{E}\left[X_t^2\right]$ and from that compute the variance?

Comment: I managed to calculate the mean $E X_t = E X_0 = 0$, but how can I find the covariance?

Comment: @htmo write down the definition of the covariance. Which piece are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well, I got stuck at this point: $Cov(X_t, X_0) = \mathbb{E}[X_{t}X_{0}] = \frac{1}{h^2} \mathbb{E}[(B_{t+h} - B_{t}) \cdot B_{h}] = \frac{1}{h^2}( \mathbb{E}[B_{t+h}B_{h}] - \mathbb{E}[B_{t}\cdot B_{h}] )$.

Comment: I know that the first term might be zero by independence, but how can I calculate the value of the second term involving t and h?

Comment: @htmo Since $B_{t+h} - B_t$ is over $[t,t+h]$ and $B_h$ is over $[0,h]$. As long as $h < t$, you can use independent increments

Comment: So, I got to the conclusion that for $t > 0$ and recalling that $\mathbb{E}[B_tB_s] = min\{t, s\}$, then: if $h < t$ we have $\mathbb{E}[X_tX_0] = 0$ and if $t < h < t+h$, then $\mathbb{E}[X_tX_0] = \frac{1}{h^2}(h-t)$.